# NServiceBus Message sent after third try

Tags: nservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus for the first time.

I have a MVC WebApp and a Server (dll). My problem: My server doesn't receive the sent message. OR, my message isn't sent. I get this messages in the output window when sending a message:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Messaging.MessageQueueException' occurred in System.Messaging.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in NServiceBus.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in NServiceBus.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in NServiceBus.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in NServiceBus.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Messaging.MessageQueueException' occurred in System.Messaging.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Messaging.MessageQueueException' occurred in System.Messaging.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Messaging.MessageQueueException' occurred in System.Messaging.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Messaging.MessageQueueException' occurred in System.Messaging.dll
x times -> A first chance exception of type 'System.Messaging.MessageQueueException' occurred in System.Messaging.dll
```

The strange thing: When I call my MVC controller 3 times in a row (pressing F5 3 times immediately) one message is sent and received on the server!!!

My global.asax.cs

```
    Configure.With()
        .DefaultBuilder()
        .ForMvc()
        .JsonSerializer()
        .Log4Net()
        .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(false)
            .PurgeOnStartup(true)
        .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
        .CreateBus()
        .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
```

And the server :

```
 Configure.With()
       .DefaultBuilder()
     .JsonSerializer();
```

What I'm doing wrong????